# MUI DateRangePicker with ONLY month and year selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Hey guys I want to create an MUI DateRangePicker with a calendar as a month-year picker, I know that's not a default option today BUT it seems we can freely customize our Pickers so I'm asking for help to create mine based on the MUI component.

Illustrating my idea:
The idea is a single input with a custom popper view/layout
[Popper with custom calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuPkS.png)

I've tried to change the DateRangePicker slots to a custom one but the custom calendar pops out the screen.

The custom view was made with DateCalendar views={['month', 'year']}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.